# Planning a mini ramp build

Tags: modifiers, measurement

playing around with bender to optimize my material use to build my 6 year old daughter 2 mini ramp (or quarter-pipe).

Building the main structured posed no problems but now I am trying to "bend a piece of plywood". The idea is I create a cube of the plywood dimensions and place it in the curvature of the ramp. That way I have excellent visuals if it fits and how much I need.

I tried simple modifier but it tends to change the size of my plywood.

What is the best way to make this work?

Plans are used from: [DIY Skate plans](http://diyskate.com/micro_quarter.html)

[image]

So basically: bend the selected box (plywood sheet) onto the curve of the quarterpipe
[image]

Comment: can you please show us in a picture what you want to have?

Comment: Maybe you could select these edges (marked green) https://i.imgur.com/rGi2sh4.png and then extrude them along X axis (E key, then X), towards the other side? This will give you a plane, that you can extrude again (or use solidify modifier) for thickness. You could also enable LoopTools add-on and *bridge* those edges with the edges on the other side.

Comment: Bending needs geometry, make sure you have enough loop cuts in the direction you are bending

Comment: I want to create a box (plenty subdivisions) with a fixed sixe (I. E. 2.5mx1.25mx0.01m). Now I want to bend it to the same curve as the transition (created by a cylinder radius 1.8m boolean). Once bent I can see how it fits/cuts. 

I know how I could create a surface to fit the image but that does not translate for me to real world measurements.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, seems that the problem I was facing was mdue to the positioning of the cylinder to the "plywood". Once I created a circle on the same origin I could bend the plate to my wishes. Now just figuring out the exact amount of degrees but for now close enough.

This gives me a rough estimate what the plate will cover

[image]